# Finding the source of a field value

Tags: content-management, language-fallback, item-clones

I guess I somewhat know the answer, but I'd like to get the community feedback on this.

What is the correct way of identifying where a field value originates from? When `item.Fields[field].HasValue` is false, the `Value` property contains a fallback value. I want to know what kind of fallback value it is. Is it the default value (the shared field on the template field item), is it from `__Standard values`, is it a language fallback value or is it from a clone source item?

The `Field` object has properties indicating this, such as `ContainsStandardValue`, `ContainsFallbackValue`, `InheritsValueFromOriginalItem`, `IsValidForLanguageFallback` and so on. Now, it turns out that those properties are actually modified when you call the `field.GetValue()` methods, and their values becomes different depending on what argument you pass to the `field.GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue, bool allowFallbackValue, bool allowInheritValue, bool allowInnerValue)` (or any of its shorter alternatives). This feels like an error in the implementation to me.

Is there a more solid, reliable or preferred way of getting this information, other than always calling `field.GetValue(true, false, true)` prior reading any of those fallback properties on the field?

**Update:**
As Mark pointed out in the comments, the issue here is that the properties "remember" the states of the last `GetValue` call. Here's a sample to illustrate this:

Let's say there is an item with a Title-field, with a `null` value, so the shown value is taken from `__Standard values`:

```
var field = item.Fields["Title"];
var title = field.Value;
var stdValue = field.ContainsStandardValue; // becomes true

title = field.GetValue(false);
stdValue = field.ContainsStandardValue; // now becomes false
```

So, the value of these properties are based on the last call to `GetValue()`, that could be code from another processor etc.

Comment: Why does it feel like an error in implementation to you?   The idea behind this abstraction is to shield developers/implementers from HOW a field fallback value comes to be, without breaking the basic item/field API code. A secondary objective is to be able to display help information in the Content Editor ([shared - standard value] and so on).

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought the intention was as well. But in my opinion it breaks. Let's say I have a field containing a standard value, and I read the `field.ContainsStandardValue` property, it'd expect it to be true. And it usually is. But if some other code, such as another processor, has called `field.GetValue(false)` prior my code, the property would read false. So the values of those properties are inconsistent.

Comment: Ah really?  now I get what you mean.  So an item - once instantiated will "remember" how its field values came to be and it will persist until you execute a GetField with alternative flags. That it?

Comment: Exactly! I guess it's for caching purposes, but I think it should only cache those values given that the `GetValue()` method is called with the expected arguments.